# Aligning the right edge of the drop down menu

Tags: css

I have the following code from [here](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/819_megamenu/demo/index.html#) which generates some fat menu:

```
<ul id="menu">

        <li class="menu_right"><a href="" class="drop">1 column</a>
            <div class="dropdown_1column align_right">

                    <div class="col_1">

                        <ul class="simple">
                            <li><a href="#">FreelanceSwitch</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Creattica</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">WorkAwesome</a></li>                            
                        </ul>   

                    </div>

            </div>
        </li></ul>
```

The style is:

```
#menu .menu_right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
#menu li .align_right {
    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
}
#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns {
    left: -1px;
    top: auto;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border: none;
}
#menu li:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}
#menu li a {        
    display: block;
    outline: 0;     
}
```

If the `right:-1px;` is removed from `#menu li:hover .align_right`, then the right edge of the drop down no longer aligns with the right edge of the parent ie "1 column" in the menubar (instead the left edge of the drop down aligns with the parent).

**What is the significance of the negative position of right**? Usually the negative value of left/right has the purpose of hiding an element as is happening for the drop down ie they are hidden normally because of negative left and are shown when the left is no longer negative.

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question. The purpose is to make sure the right edge aligns correctly with the parent.

Comment: What happens if you replace -1 with 0 ?

Comment: It simply won't be inline anymore. Why would you want to remove that styling?

Comment: I don't want to remove the style. I want to understand the effect of negative value - in one case it makes an element disappear and in another case it makes right alignment. Very confusing indeed.

Answer (score 4):

i got the solution please check it http://jsfiddle.net/v4Jwu/

**HTML**

```
<select>
<option value="1">Client: Zac Brown Band</option>
<option value="2">Saab</option>
<option value="3">Mercedes</option>
<option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select { direction: rtl; }
```

Comment: This is a surprisingly simple solution to the problem.

Comment: I voted it up because it really is a nice answer. However, it's not valid for me because I need the arrow to be to the right... Any suggestions?